# How to install missing Wine ALSA driver in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, audio, wine

Whenever I try to run a Windows game under Wine I get an error that says I don't have a proper sound driver.

I checked the Wine config and there was only an OSS option that I think wouldn't be useful in getting the sound working. I think I have to use ALSA instead but I don't know how to add ALSA support to Wine.

I use:

- Ubuntu (Meerkat) 10.10
- Wine 1.2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Install alsa-oss packages then do

```
aoss wine */Pathtothegame/thegame.exe*
```